# Using pg_dump and psql ,pg_restore not working for migration Postgres from 9.6.11 to 9.6.18

Tags: postgresql

Source db is Postgres RDS 9.6.11 version
Target db is Postgres RDS 9.6.18 version

I am trying to migrate the data from source to target db using postgres native tools.
But Its not working for me..

```
pg_dump --host  qatest.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -c -Fc -U username -d username >qadump_original_fc.sql

pg_restore -U postgres -d postgres -Fc  -h qatest.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com qadump_original_fc.sql
```

> pg_restore: [archiver] did not find magic string in file header

```
pg_restore -U postgres -d postgres  -h qatest.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com qadump_original_fc.sql
```

> pg_restore: [archiver] input file does not appear to be a valid archive

Using psql to import throwing multiple errors like Invalid large objects,syntax error etc,.

I have tried with and without -Fc in pg_dump for pg_restore and psql, but no luck.

Comment: can you check the first few lines of the file qatest.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com qadump_original_fc.sql

Comment: Its all encrypted ^@^@^@test^@^E^@^@^@false^A^A^@^@^@^C^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@ÿ<^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^D^@^@^@2613^@^E^@^@^@38048^@^E^@^@^@38048^@^D^@^@^@BLOB^@^B^@^@^@^@&^@^@^@SELECT pg_catalog.lo_create('38048');
^@&^@^@^@SELECT pg_catalog.lo_unlink('38048');
^A^A^@^@^@^A^A^@^@^@^A^A^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@test^@^E^@^@^@false^A^A^@^@^@^C^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@=^SELECT pg_catalog.lo_create('38050');
^@&^@^@^@SELECT pg_catalog.lo_unlink('38050');

Comment: Are you using **pg_dump**, **pg_restore** and **psql** from the 9.6.11 or the 9.6.18 installation for this task, or a different one from either?

Comment: You should be using `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` from the target system. To find out which version you are using run `pg_dump --version` and `pg_restore --version`

Comment: The `pg_dump` you show doesn't write `qadump_original_fc.sql`.

Comment: I edited it now..Thankyou @Laurenz Albe

Comment: Then either this is not PostgreSQL (fork?) or it cannot happen.

Comment: I now tried with correct versions of postgres client at source and target.still same error pg_restore -U postgres -d postgres  -h  qatestdb.csjaan7ysedb.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com qadump_original_fc_9615.dump
pg_restore: [archiver] input file does not appear to be a valid archive

Comment: Also when I try psql,I am getting below error,                                                            psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -U postgres -d postgres  -h newpostgresdb.csjaan7ysedb.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -f qadump_original_9615_plain_unzip.dump
Password for user postgres:
psql:qadump_original_9615_plain_unzip.dump:3: ERROR:  large object 38560 does not exist

Comment: I fixed this error by adding -o in pgdump.Now I am getting new error,psql:qadump_original_9615_new1_uncompressed.dump:1: ERROR:  relation "public.cert_chain" does not exist